# What is more secure: encrypting individual files in archive or encrypting the archive itself?

Tags: encryption, aes, zip

Let's assume we have symmetric crypto with the same IV for each operation.

From my perspective, encrypting the whole archive is better, as similar strings are compacted and the CBC will work for us even if there are same regions.

Encrypting the individual files, however, will produce ciphertext with the same starting sequences, as files often have similar magic bytes or media headers. This will help the attacker to guess what files are there and maybe even crack the encryption.

Is my train of thought correct here?

Comment: "secure" from *what*? Until you can define what you want to protect against, comparing different protections will be difficult. Is it a risk that someone can know what the filetypes are? "ciphertext with the same starting sequences" --what type of encryption are you using where this happens?

Comment: Why would you ever intentionally repeat the (key, IV) pair? Use a new IV for every file. Also, CBC is not state of the art, nothing modern uses CBC. All modern encryption is an AEAD and ~all AEADs are built on CTR, where of course you need to use a new nonce for every file.

Comment: @Z.T. I don't control the encryption process, so I assume worst. Hope it's GCM/CTR.

Comment: @schroeder secure from decryption by 3rd party. I don't know yet which encryption scheme will be chosen.

Comment: Secure *all* files from being decrypted? Or is there a specific file in the archive that you don't want decrypted? If you don't know what encryption will be used, then trying to debate the relative merits and weaknesses of a specific encryption *process* is moot.

Comment: @schroeder yes, secure all files from being decrypted. I still didn't get an answer for my question. Given abstract opaque encryption process, is it more secure to encrypt individual files or the whole archive?

Comment: If you encrypt the whole archive, you only need to succeed once to decrypt everything. If you encrypt each file individually, then you need to succeed on each file. The logic seems clear: encrypt each one individually to protect the *collection*.